# How can you select cells highlighted by conditional formatting?

Tags: excel, highlight, conditional-formatting

I've applied conditional formatting to all cells in a table so that those with a character length of 3 are highlighted in yellow.

[image]

How can I select all **highlighted** cells at once? I can't search for yellow cells, and **Go To Special > Conditional formats** highlights all cells with conditional formatting applied, not just those that are highlighted (i.e., where the condition is TRUE).

Comment: What's the purpose of you selecting all the cells? You will have to resort VBA for something like that. Instead of selecting the cell, you can process what you want to do directly with VBA.

Answer (score 1):

A VBA macro that selects all cells formatted in yellow could look like this:

```
Sub SelectYellow()
    Dim Rng as Range
    MinRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row
    MinCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Column
    MaxRow = MinRow + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
    MaxCol = MinCol + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1
    For I = MinRow To MaxRow
        For J = MinCol To MaxCol
            Set myCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(I, J)
            If myCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
                If Not Rng is Nothing Then
                    Set Rng = Union(Rng, myCell)
                Else 
                    Set Rng = myCell
                End If
            End If
        Next J
    Next I
    Rng.Select
End Sub
```

Note that instead of `myCell.Interior.ColorIndex` you need to use  `myCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex` in case of conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use colour as a selection attribute, whether it is set manually or by conditional formatting (you might get this done using VBA).

Best way is to use the same conditions you have entered for defining the conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

For my purposes I just had one column that was colorized by conditional formatting, so I was able to sort by cell color. Hope this helps